# Uneven assignment of tasks to workers in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink batch job which operates on a large dataset. My cluster consists of 25 nodes and runs as a standalone cluster. One of the key steps has a parallelism of 70 and I expected each task manager to get between 2 and 3 slots for that step, instead only half the workers are used and some of them are getting up to 8 slots assigned (which is the maximum they can get).

Apart from the impact on data locality, another side effect is the strain on disk space. Since less workers are running all the slots, each one of them has to store more data compared to having the slots spread across all the nodes of the cluster.

Am I missing something? Is there a way I can force Flink to distribue the slots across as many TMs as possible for each job?

Comment: Same here, we recorded the same characteristic by migrating from Flink-1.3.2 to Flink-1.6.2.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, Flink does not support to spread out tasks evenly across the set of available `TaskManagers`. The reason is that Flink considers every slot to be equal. In the future, the Flink community plans to add more scheduling features which would solve the problem.

At the moment, I would suggest to set the individual operator's parallelism to the number of available slots in your cluster. That will guarantee that all machines of your cluster are evenly used.

Comment: thanks. If a job has multiple tasks e.g. join followed by group reduce, I'd need to give them 50% of the slots each, which is pretty much the situation I'm in at the moment where they both use only half the workers. Having said that the UI is telling me that the number of free slots is greater than I think. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Per default Flink enables slot sharing which allows operators to be deployed into the same slot. This means that each join sub task runs together with another reduce sub task in the same slot. If you don't want this behaviour, then you have to assign a different slot sharing group name to one of these operators.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Anyway, I guess choosing always the highest parallelism is not convenient in those cases having multiple business logic to run, then, different jobs: here, if we want to spread computation over different nodes for the whole jobs it'd really depend on Flink and its tasks distribution.

Comment: I've set the parallelism to the total number of slots (that are spread across two nodes), but the coGroup function is still only run on a single TaskManager (on one node). I need it to spread it across all of the TaskManagers to maximise use of all available CPUs.

Comment: Could you share some details about the job your are running @ndtreviv?

Comment: @TillRohrmann What do you want to know? I've got two Tuple4's. I'm doing a co-group using a custom CoGroupFunction. I have two nodes in the cluster, 16 slots spread evenly across them, and the coGroup is being done in one slot.

Comment: @TillRohrmann Maybe I should ask another question on SO here to bottom it out?

Comment: If the coGroup is only run in one slot, then I guess its parallelism is set to `1`. Could you check in the web UI that this is not the case?

Comment: @TillRohrmann Parallelism is set to the total number of slots (in this case 16) for that CoGroup according to the UI.

Comment: I think it's because, in my test, the coGroup is being keyed on a single-value field. ie: `tuple4_1.coGroup(tuple4_2).where(1).equalTo(1)` but the field it's joining on - there is only one possible value. Could that be right?

Comment: Yes, then all records will go to the same `coGroup` function.